# bootstrap 4 card text goes off the card-text

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to put a text in a card-text paragraph but when I put It that happens:

[image: the text goes out of the container]

I'm trying to fix it but I can't, I'm without any kind of idea of how to fix it. The source code:

```
<div class='card'>
      <img class='card-img-top img-fluid' width="100%" src="{$post['imagen']}" alt=''>
      <div class='card-block'>
        <h4 class='card-title'>{$post['titulo']}</h4>
        <p class='card-text'>{$post['descripcion']}</p>
        <p class='card-text'><h6><a href="./categoria/{$post['categoria']}"><span class="tag tag-success"><i class="fa fa-tag" aria-hidden="true"></i> {$post['categoria']}</span></a></h6></p>
        <p class="text-muted card-text hidden-sm-up"></i>{$fecha}</p>
        <a href="./post/{$post['id']}" class='btn btn-primary hidden-sm-down'><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> Leer más</a>
        <a href="./post/{$post['id']}" class='btn btn-primary hidden-sm-up btn-block'><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> Leer más</a>
        <p class="pull-xs-right text-muted card-text hidden-sm-down">{$fecha}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I'm also using PHP. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Does setting ``word-wrap`` correct the problem? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Comment: yep, that solved the issue. Thanks  :)

Answer (score 0):

As

> @NuclearPeon

says, the `word-wrap` in the styles.css